# Error: call to a member function bind_param() , when doing 2nd bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql

I got the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean
```

on this line:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $r);
```

Is my query prepared correctly?
I checked the name of the table and columns and they are correct

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE db_control SET cve_usuario=? WHERE cve_control=1");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $r);
```

heres my whole code:

```
<?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "usuario";
            $password = "usuario";
            $database = "proyectofinal";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT cve_usuario FROM db_control");
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $stmt->bind_result($r);
                if($stmt->fetch()){
                    echo $r;
                }

                $r = $r + 1;

                echo "<br>" . $r;

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE db_control SET cve_usuario=? WHERE cve_control=1");
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $r);
                if($stmt->execute())
                {
                    /*do something*/
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: The standard answer to that is: because your query fails (to prepare).

Comment: I would change the names of your second prepared varibales, `$stmt2` maybe. Your code is not clear to me, `SELECT cve_usuario FROM db_control` is only pulling the first `cve_usuario`. You then are increasing the value once and updating all records to that value `WHERE cve_control=1`. You could do that with one select but the logic seems off.

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation of `mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

> #### Return Values
>
> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

You should check that the `prepare` call succeeded with a strict check (`$stmt !== FALSE`), though a simple `if ($stmt)` works *in this specific case* also.

If you want to know what made your `prepare` call fail, you can check the error code / message:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("...");
if ($stmt) {
  // bind parameters, execute statement, etc
} else {
  echo "MySQLi error: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it! Forgot to close the connection before preparing the 2nd query.

That do the trick! Thanks